# Getting the latest main tag version from git using git describe

Tags: git

I have lot of tags for candidate and dev like:

- 1.1.1-dev.2
- 1.1.2-rc.0

i would like to get the last main tag in git that match to production semver

for example : for version  1.1.2-rc.0

i will get the last production tag that was **1.1.1**

i was trying the following:

```
git describe --tags --abbrev=1
```

```
 git describe  --abbrev=0  | awk -F - '{print $1}'
```

will give me 1.1.2 but there is no tag like that

Answer (score 0):

> i would like to get the last main tag in git that match to production semver

Tags, in Git, are not on branches.  They are on commits.  So "main tag" does not seem to mean anything.

> ```
> git describe --abbrev=0 | awk -F - '{print $1}'
> ```
>
> will give me 1.1.2 but there is no tag like that

Of course: you told `awk` to treat `-` as a field separator, so that `1.1.2-rc.0` was treated as two fields containing `1.1.2` and `rc.0`: those are the two strings that are separated by the `-` character.  Then you told `awk` to print the *first* field, ignoring the *second one* entirely, and it did exactly what you asked.

The `git describe` command here may be the wrong tool to use.  It's not clear what the right tool would be, as it's not clear from your question what tag you want based on the specific commit.  However, if what you want is:

- the `git describe` tag if it *does not* end with `-rc*` (glob syntax), or
- the `git describe` tag converted to a three-part number, minus 1, if it *does* end with `rc*`

then you can do that with `git describe`.  The problem with *this* is likely to occur at boundaries: if you're on `1.1.2-rc0` it's pretty clear that the previous version would be `1.1.1`, but if you're on `1.1.0-rc3` for instance, is the previous version 1.0.0`,` 1.0.19`, or what?  What does *previous version* mean in this context?  Why do you *need* a "previous version" in the first place?

You may need to write a program to compute the answer you want, depending on what the *question* is.  You'll need to figure out your precise question first.